# requests post returning 200 in python, while postman returns 201

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I'm calling an API using python requests and response code is 200. For same data and post request, Postman is returning status code 201 created.

How can I achive 201 in python?

Sample code in python:

```
base_url=https://domain-name.com/api/import/
list=["9273e6b66c9487bda40b6090492407f", "610a28885cd1f8f4cb04ee20440e42f3"]
action="add"
headers = {
        'Authorization': api_key,
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}

payload = {
        "md5s": list,
        "action": action
}

response = requests.post(base_url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Can someone point me where went wrong?

Below is postman code:

```
POST /api/import/ HTTP/1.1
Host: domain-name.com
Authorization: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx

{"md5s":["9273e6b66c9487bda40b6090492407f", "610a28885cd1f8f4cb04ee20440e42f3"],"action":"add"}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the api class please?

Comment: You included very little information about the server. I guess your Python code does not provide the `User-Agent` header and the server responds differently. Both 200 and 201 are "good" codes, probably there is no need to panic.

Comment: But 201 is still a successful response, isn't it?

Comment: 201 means you created a new resource.

Comment: I'm not getting 201 using python script. I have a base url, which looks something like https://domain-name.com/api/import/.
Using postman, i was able to add the list in server.
Using python, not able to add the list in the server.

Comment: @DYZ Just tired by adding user agent
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'

still getting 200.

Comment: Could you paste the whole request in postman?

Comment: have you already authenticated in your python code? didn't you get the 201 at that point?

Comment: @Sraw added postman code in the question.

Comment: How about you delete that `'Content-Type':'application/json',` and then use `json=payload` instead of `data=json.dumps(payload)`?

Comment: @Sraw tried removing      'Content-Type':'application/json' and used      data=payload. Still getting response code 200

Comment: Not `data = payload` but `json = payload`.

Comment: @Sraw yeah, tried `json=payload` . No luck. Same 200

Comment: Well, that's strange. You can use `response.request.headers` and `response.request.body` to see the sent request. Maybe that will be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184737/discussion-between-naveen-and-sraw).

Comment: Issue is with the url, there is small spelling mistake.
Thanks a lot @Sraw for you help. Appreciate it.